# Pygame keyup/keydown sometimes works

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on the Alien Invasion game from Python Crash Course.pdf

```
import sys

import pygame

def check_events(ship):
    """respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ship)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)

def check_keydown_events(event, ship):
    """respond to keypresses."""

    if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            ship.moving_right = True

    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            ship.moving_left = True

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """respond to key releases."""

    if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            ship.moving_right = False
    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            ship.moving_left = False
                # Move the ship to the right.
                #ship.rect.centerx += 1

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship):
    """update images on screen and flip to the new screen"""
    #redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()

    #make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()
```

```
#alien invasion

import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    #intialize pygame, settings , and screen object

    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # Make a Ship
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)


#set the background color
    #bg_color = (52, 86, 139)

    # start the main loop for the game
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ship)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)

            #watch for keyboard and mouse events.

        #redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        ship.blitme()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

            #make the most recently drawn screen visible

        pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

```
import pygame


class Ship():

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        #store a decimal value for the ships center
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

        #Movement flags
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        """update the ships position based on the movement flag"""
        # Update the ships center value, not the rect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        # Update rect object from self.center
        self.rect.centerx = self.center

        if self.moving_right:
            self.rect.centerx += 1
        if self.moving_left:
            self.rect.centerx -= 1

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location."""
     #   pygame.draw.rect(self, (255,0,0), (100, 100), 36)
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

```
class Settings():
    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion"""

    def __init__(self):
        """intialize the games settings."""
        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (52, 86, 139)

        #ship settings
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
```

This is the code from my game_functions class

When I press 'D', 85% of the time nothing happens. Sometimes it non stop slides to the left or right, either or. Same thing when pressing "A".

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong in this code? This code is fairly basic I just want it to move left or right.

Comment: Please provide the code snippet where `check_events()` method is being called.

Comment: added all the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Their is no code that turns `self.moving_right` and `self.moving_left` to
`false` to stop them from moving.
I would use something like this:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP :
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        self.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE :
        self.moving_left = False
```

Here's the documantation:
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html